# Can I have an application always open on Android?

Tags: android

I don't know much about Android multitasking but I thought I'd ask the question before I attempt my project.

Is there a way I can program an Android application (aimed at Android 4.0+ only) to always be open in the background and keep all the network connections alive and the UI "drawn" so that when I open it, it ALWAYS opens instantly and I can use it instantly even if the tablet is doing something else?

Thanks.

Comment: It's really bad practice if you ask me. You should save the state e load it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you want to create a [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground). A foreground service is a service that the user is aware of and is not considered a candidate to kill if Android is running out of memory. It is associated to a persistent notification bar, that the user can tap to bring to the foreground an activity. To make sure that the network connection are not switched off, your service should acquire a [wake lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html).

However, please remember that a long running process that potentially kills the battery is considered a bad practice, and you should avoid doing this unless you have really really strong reasons to do it.

Answer (score 0):

No, Android is not build like that. The OS can always kill services/activities in the background when it needs more resources.

You can make services which are always running (sticky service) which restarts if it is killed because of resource problems, when there are resources again available.
With Activies you cannot do that. But it could be happen that your activity is 'paused' and still in the background, so it can be 'resumed' very quickly. But again Android can easily kill it for resources.

Comment: Note that if you follow this and use a service, you'll still need an Activity for the UI you mentioned (to the OP, not @PoweRoy)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can have an application *always* running in the background, unless you modify Android at the firmware level and build your own version. Android kills other apps as and when it needs more resources to run the app currently in the foreground.

However, it is possible to make your app better at handling this by saving data and it's current state in [onPause()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) and restoring the same in [onResume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29).